# Relevance of Landau's Algorithm for Denesting Radicals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algorithms

I just came across a Wikipedia article [Nested Radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Landau%27s_algorithm) that mentions [Landau's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Landau%27s_algorithm&redirect=no) for deciding, whether a nested radical can be denested, but that Wikipedia article is just a stub.
Googling "Landau's Algorithms" produces references to the Wang and Landau Algorithm.

> **Question:**
>
> What role does Landau's Algorithm play in mathematical research, i.e. did it pave the way for further progress, e.g. towards a deterministic algorithm for denesting radicals, or did it "just" solve an isolated problem?
>
> I am asking because [the original article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2629046_Simplification_of_Nested_Radicals) is freely accessible online, but isn't described in the omniscient Wikipedia.
> Is my impression right, that because Ramanujan provided some examples of denested radicals, that the topic is of some relevance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 2017 article [Gkioulekas - On the denesting of nested square roots](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314248287_On_the_denesting_of_nested_square_roots) summarizes the status of this topic. Landau's algorithm is not a "final" solution because it runs in exponential time with respect to the depth of the expression that one is attempting to denest. To find a general algorithm that runs in polynomial time remains an open problem. See also this related [MSE posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4697/87355).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I thought I remembered a massive re-organisation that rendered all ResearchGate links pointing to the wrong place.  (Maybe I'm thinking of CiteSeer.)  Anyway, though it can probably rot even more easily, here's a link to the article on the author's home page:  [Gkioulekas - On the de-nesting of nested square roots](https://faculty.utrgv.edu/eleftherios.gkioulekas/papers/submitted/denesting-square-roots.pdf).

Comment: Also, I edited to add the name of the author of the paper, but apparently did so while you were making your own edit, with the result that the system thought I was deleting your edit.  I apologise, and think I have restored your intended edit.